# How to use a package in another package residing at other location of the hard disk in Java?

Tags: java, oop, package

How to use a package in another package residing at other location of the hard disk in Java?

```
//Saved at G:

package p5;

public class Temp5 {

  public void show() {
    System.out.println("PACKAGE P1");  
  }

  public static void main(String... s) {
    Temp5 t1=new Temp5();  
    t1.show();  
  }   
}

//saved at H:

package p6;

import p5.*;

public class Temp6 {

  public static void main(String... s)  {
    Temp5 t1=new Temp5();   
    t1.show();

  } 
}
```

How we can compile these two packages and how to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compile them separately, and run using this command:

`java -classpath <path to external class> <name of main class>`

Comment: both the files compiled successfully...but at running time it displays an error:
could not find or load main class Temp6

Comment: when i try to run:
java -classpath H: p6.Temp

it displays an error that
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFound error: p5.Temp5 at p6.Temp6.main<Temp6.java:7>

Comment: I think this is due to having package names, try to compile with `javac -d . <nameofclass>` (if i remember correctly, google the error message and you will find a stackoverflow question related to this and package names..)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE, link any one of the packages as a dependency of the other package. This can be done under build path->Source tab. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

One option as suggested above is to use -classpath or -cp in short argument.

But if you don't like setting it through command line then you can also make use of classpath environment variable.